# Как передать параметры в метод как объект?

Tags: javascript

Например, есть у меня объект с различными методами.

Как можно для этих методов задать параметры, используя для этого объект, как например реализовано во многих плагинах, например jQuery:

```
$('#some').some({
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right'
});
```

Comment: в примере вы и так передаете объект в метод, проблема то в чем?

Comment: Особых проблем нет. Кроме одной - JS начал изучать недавно и пока нет четкого понятия того, как правильно реализовать передачу параметра как объекта и его последующей обработки

Comment: Так же существует целый набор разных паттернов и best practice создания плагинов для jQuery. http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/#jquery-plugin-patterns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это паттерн передачи опций. Когда метод имеет множество настроек, и их значения по умолчанию, а параметром можно передать объект опций с измененными значениями. Внутри, метод объединит их: переданные значения приоритетнее дефолтных.

У [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#assign), [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) и др. библиотек есть удобный метод `extend()` для объединения свойств: главному объекту дописываются/перезаписываются свойства из следующих объектов.

Например, метод для формирования тега картинки:

```
myObject = {
    myMethod: function( opts){
        var props = { // заполнен значениями по-умолчанию
            width: "100px",
            height: "100px",
            src: "noimage.png",
            alt: "",
            title: "",
        };

        jQuery.extend( props, opts);

        // теперь в props объединены св-ва
        return '<img src="' +props.src 
            +'" width="' +props.width 
            +'" height="' +props.height
            +'" alt="' +props.alt
            +'" title="' +props.title
            +'" />';
    }
}
```

Его можно вызвать, указав только те свойства, что отличаются от дефолтных:

```
var imgTag = myObject.myMethod({
    src   : "avatar.jpg",
    title : "Вася Пупкин",
});
```

Вернет код тега, где ширина/высота по-прежнему 100.

---

**Update** этот паттерн, в частности, [описан в руководстве](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/) по разработке плагинов, как раз, к jQuery (на англ.).

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем корректно задан вопрос. Попробую ответить:

```
var someObj = {
   a:1,
   b:2
};

function someFunc(obj) {
   alert(obj.a);
};

someFunc(someObj);
```

Как видно из примера, функция принимает параметром объект.